# Updating Frontier because of InvalidCode(Opcode(95))

Tags: smart-contract, evm, frontier, gas

I'm utilizing the Polkadot branch v0.9.37 within a Substrate-based standalone chain. Presently, when deploying smart contracts using the latest version of Solidity, I encounter the following error:

> Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The
> transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
> Returned error: evm error: InvalidCode(Opcode(95))

This error is because of new version of Solidity with PUSH0(0x5f) opcode

Following are Questions

- Should I update all pallets to the latest version, or would updating
  just the Frontier pallet suffice?
- If updating only the Frontier pallet is adequate, which version of
  Frontier is compatible with `v0.9.37`?

Please Answer

Comment: What version of the Solidity compiler are you using?
1. It should be 
2. Frontier version v0.9.37 is compatible with `polkadot-v0.9.37`

Comment: @CocDap i'm using 0.8.24 version of Solidity and Polkadot polkadot-v0.9.37 is not compatible with latest version of solidity.

Comment: yeah i guess that. you can try older version like 0.8.0

Comment: @CocDap yes, it's working on older versions of Solidity but i want my chain compatible with new version of Solidity like 0.8.24. 
That's the only reason to update chain.